# Javascript condensing - defining many variables in one line

Tags: javascript, performance, function, definitions

We generally have the understanding that functions in javascript are used to execute blocks of code with a single call. However, I'm currently working in a system that contains many functions which require many variables to be defined, so I'm seeing a lot of repeat code. I'd love to put the variable declarations in a function so they don't take a whole bunch of space, but is something similar to that even possible?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: *"I'm currently working in a system that contains many functions which require many variables to be defined, so I'm seeing a lot of repeat code."* Code is worth 1,024 words. It's not clear what you're describing. *Showing* is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd love to put the variable declarations in a function so they don't take a whole bunch of space, but is something similar to that even possible?

If you mean:

```
function one() {
   var a, b, c, d, e, f;
   // ...
}
function two() {
   var a, b, c, d, e, f;
   // ...
}
```

(E.g., each function has its *own* copy of the variables.)

...and you want

```
// Doesn't work
function declare() {
   var a, b, c, d, e, f;
}
function one() {
    declare();
    // ...use a, b, etc. here
}
function two() {
    declare();
    // ...use a, b, etc. here
}
```

No, you cannot do that.

You might consider encapsulating the variables in an object, if the same set of variables is used in multiple places. In fact, the whole thing sounds like it might be refactored as an object.

But without too much refactoring:

```
function declare() {
    return {
        a: /*...*/,
        b: /*...*/,
        c: /*...*/,
        d: /*...*/,
        e: /*...*/,
        f: /*...*/,
    };
}
function one() {
    var o = declare();
    // ...use o.a, o.b, etc.
}
function two() {
    var o = declare();
    // ...use o.a, o.b, etc.
}
```

But again, that's the minimal-impact solution. It's like that if you look at your overall code with the idea that you could organize things a bit into objects, you'd find a less artificial way than the above.

Comment: Thought that too. The `declare` function is not even needed, if the object is declared in a common scope to all functions.

Comment: This solution would work very well in this scenario. Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: @bfavaretto: No, there's a *big* difference there. With the `declare` function, `one` and `two` get their *own* copies of the vars. With a common scope, they share. (Which is what the *"E.g., each function has its own copy of the variables"* bit of the above was about.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to do, it's probably best not to do it manually. You can just use a minifier, such as uglify or Google's Closure Compiler. These tools can be used to optimize your JS files' size significantly, and you can keep your original code readable.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions, perhaps the simplest one is just relying on closures:

```
(function(){}
    // declare all vars here
    var a = 1, b = 2;

    // var a will be available here
    function foo() {
        alert(a);
    }

    foo();
}());
```